# Privileges for declaring MySQL variables?

Tags: mysql

When I try to `DECLARE output_text VARCHAR(20);` i get the following error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE output_text VARCHAR(20)' at line 1**

I running phpmyadmin MySQL version: 5.0.45-community-nt. Do I need special privileges to declare variables and functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `DECLARE` statement is standing on its own, which is [illegal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: BEGIN DECLARE output_text VARCHAR(20); END ... I tried this and still receive the same error.

Comment: @Enki are you in a stored procedure with this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html

Comment: no I cant get stored procedures to work either, I am executing within phpmyadmin, should I execute from the cmd line?

Comment: @Enki you can define stored procedures in phpMyAdmin but you may need to change the delimiter. What do you want to do, what is your final goal?

Comment: I am just trying learn more about MySQL, but final goal is to create compound statement for converting and transferring data from table to another. I executed SHOW GRANTS and it shows no privileges for procedures or variables.